# animation is not executing after property is set to a variable

Tags: jquery

While I was trying to make a slider I need to make it conditionally apply `marginLeft` or `marginTop` on this, so I was trying to take it from a returning variable value.

But, I dived into a problem and after a lot of struggle found exactly what the problem is ===> I cannot take variable value for jQuery method. I firstly thought that `var something = 'margin-left';` would not work as `{margin-left : ...}` not work without the quote and so tried it with `marginLeft` like the example below:

This works :

```
$(selector).click(function(){
    $(element).animate({
        marginLeft: '-=600'
```

This also works :

```
$(selector).click(function(){
var toLeft = '-=600';
    $(element).animate({
        marginLeft: toLeft
```

But why not this? :

```
$(selector).click(function(){
var move = 'marginLeft';
    $(element).animate({
        move: '-=600'
```

## [see this not working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u6QjG/)

Huh! Assigning property taking from variable for jQuery method to use in `{property : value}` method is not allowed ?

How can I make it work ? Or, is it a bug ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an object in this syntax,

```
{
    property: value
}
```

the property name cannot be a variable. The very name you use here would be the name of the property. In your case:

```
var move = 'marginLeft';
    $(element).animate({
        move: '-=600'
```

the property is named "move", instead of "marginLeft".

To achieve what you want, do this:

```
var move = 'marginLeft';
var options = {};
options[move] = '-=20';
$(element).animate(options);
```

And now here is your [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u6QjG/1/).